# Finding the matrix which generate a vector series

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, time-series

We have vectors $v_0,\ldots,v_k$ in $\Bbb R^n$. Find the matrix A which minimizes the $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}|Av_i-v_{i+1}|$.

Comment: We edited the question with mathjax,  please check if it is still what you ask,  and make if any amendment

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: $k$ is fixed, or you want to find a matrix $A(k)$?

Comment: $k$ is fixed. @JoséCFerreira.

Comment: Kind of an idea how to solve this - note that the minimum must exist because of compactness. Also, it looks like it must be unique in most cases (other-wise any convex combination of minimums is also a minimum). So, for any i and j, one can look at the expression we want to minimize as a function of 1-variable $a_{ij}$ i.e. an entry of $A$ in i row and j column. The derivative at the $a_{ij}^{min}$ should be zero. So, we get a number of equations on the entries of the matrix which sets minimum.

Comment: I agree, if the problem is repleaced by $\min_A\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\|Av_i-v_{i+1}\|^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the minimizing problem
$$\min_A\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\|Av_i-v_{i+1}\|,$$ as
$$\begin{cases} \min_A\quad \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} t_i  \\ s.t\,\,\,\,\,\, \quad \|Av_i-v_{i+1}\|^2 = t_i^2  \end{cases} .$$

If you see the matrix $A$ as a [long vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), you can try to solve it umerically with [constrOptim](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/constrOptim) tool, for instance.

You can find many math.stackexchange related discussions by searching for "[constrained linear programming minimizers](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=linear%20programming%20minimizers) " on SearchOnMath.